# Im getting an error : Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'char'

Tags: c#

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            var words = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
            foreach (var w in words)
            {
                if (w == ' ')
```

The error is on w == ' '

Comment: `if (w == " ")` ..... using single quotes makes it a `char` (not a `string`)

Comment: Also, if you're splitting on `' '`, `w == " "` will never be true.

Comment: Exactly why `var`s are a bad idea!

Comment: @Liam: I'm not sure if that was sarcasm. Are you saying the solution would have been to use `foreach (string w in words)`... and then watch as the user would have gotten the exact same error message?

Comment: Hi @MarkHildreth, no my point is, vars hide the underlying data type in the code and make it harder to read. It makes things like this harder to spot. C# is a strongly typed language why hide this? Useful for anonymous types, that's it as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Liam: I believe we have a divergence of opinion then, something that probably won't be solved in these comments. More importantly, why on earth is this question being downvoted? There's an error message, and a code sample from which the error message derives.

Comment: @MarkHildreth Yes, and that's a poor quality question, just a dump of code with an error message it produces, where's the research, where's the effort spent diagnosing the problem, etc.?

Comment: @Servy: Perhaps your right. Maybe after viewing so many questions without any code or error messages at all, a question that has just those appears positively great to me :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`textBox1.Text.Split` returns an array of strings and so your `w` is a string. Single quotes are used for chars and double quotes for strings. Therefore, it should be

```
if (w == " ")
```

Answer (score 4):

You might be getting a bit confused. In C# you can't interchange `'` and `"`. They mean different things. `'` is a char separator. `"` is a string separator. A char is not a string, and `var w` is a string. What you need is this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var words = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
foreach (var w in words)
{
    if (w == " ") //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Split` returns an array of `String`s.

If foo is a `String` and bar is a `char`, then `foo == bar` is invalid.

Instead of

```
(w == ' ')
```

you can use this:

```
w.Equals(" ")
```

Comment: I'm curious, why did you choose to use `.equals()` instead of `==`?

Comment: @MikePrecup Because he wants it to throw an exception if `w` is `null`?  Also, given the casing of the method, it's pretty clear he's a java programmer, and in java `==` isn't overloaded for `string`.

Comment: @Servy Java is the usual reason I see given for the usage (good catch on the casing). Always interesting to hear about other reasons, though, such as the `null`, although I think an explicit check would make intent much more clear in that case.

Comment: @MikePrecup I was actually explaining why `Equals` is *inferior* over `==`, admittedly using a sarcastic tone.  If you used the static `string.Equals(a,b)` then it would work, and just be a matter of preference.

Comment: @Servy I've always stuck with `==` for readability/consistency, but the MSDN recommends to `Use an overload of the String.Equals method to test whether two strings are equal`, which has always been a point of confusion for me. I'm still trying to find a good answer as to why that would be preferred. Perhaps to ensure consistency even if a `StringComparison` option is used? I may well post this question, since I see no compelling reason to prefer that.

Comment: @MikePrecup That would be an opinion based question more than anything, so isn't really appropriate on SO.  In any case, I see no reason not to use `==`.

Comment: @MikePrecup, don't be sarcastic, mate :) Equals is not inferior to == if we look at the fact that one can use StringComparison as an option. Also, I do not consider the == among strings elegant. C# is an object-oriented technology, so == should compare the object ids as well, not just the object values if used among objects in my opinion. == meaning congruency in some cases and meaning similarity in other cases is an inconsistency if you ask me. If you are using reflection and you do not know whether you are comparing strings, then what will you use? Naturally, the Equals method.

Comment: Oups, my message was meant to be sent to @Servy, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Ah, I've deleted my comment since it's no longer relevant. I did want to point out one thing I just thought of, though: comparing string references gets dangerous. The compiler is optimized to reuse string instances where it can, which could result in some very odd behavior if you were comparing string references.

Comment: @LajosArpad `Equals` is inferior in this context because you aren't null checking.  You either need to spend the extra time and effort to null check or your function doesn't actually *work*.  If you need to use a custom comparer (which isn't used here) then I would use the static `string.Equals` rather than the instance method.  I see no use for the instance version personally.  `==` is defined as being equality; it means whatever the type says it means, just like the `Equals` method.  That some other languages, exclusively use it for a bitwise comparison of the variables doesn't mean much.

Comment: @LajosArpad Also, C# isn't a purely object oriented language.  It's merely a language that incorporates certain aspects of object oriented programming when it finds them useful.  To paraphrase Eric Lippert, C# is a pragmatic language; it implements whatever features result in it being most useful for it's users.  In some cases this means incorporating object oriented styles, and in some cases it means using non-object oriented features.

Comment: @Servy A null is not a word if you ask me. Also, do you think there is a potential for Split to return a string array where at least an element is null?

Comment: @LajosArpad The use of the instance `Equals` methods forces the programming to ask themselves that question whenever the use it, and deal with the resulting crashes in the event that they were wrong.  The use of `==` prevents the developer from even needing to ask themselves that question.  Given that there are times that methods sometimes do return `null` values when they shouldn't (even if that isn't possible in this one example) makes this a problem I'd rather not waste my time thinking about.

Comment: I sleep better if I see an exception whenever undesired behavior happens, this way errors will not go unnoticed. Imagine the case when it is absolutely invalid to have a null value, but the application doesn't tell you about this. If this goes unobserved for months, your database will be full of junk. If null is valid, then we allow null to be occurred. If null is invalid, it is much better to have an exception than to have a hidden bug.